# IE8 doesnt show open in new tab or window in context menu for anchor

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, contextmenu, openinfowindowhtml

Well, I have a menu that has a structure similar to

```
<ul id="principal_menu">
   <li><a href="example.com"> menu 1</a> </li>
   <li><a href="example.com"> menu 2</a> </li>
</ul>
```

... and there in the page are other links like

```
<a id="works">this link shows the open in new tab or window</a>
```

the links in the #principal_menu doesnt show the open in new tab or window at right click but #works does and they are both

suggestions?

thanks

Comment: do you have a URL we can test this on? my only guess is that the menu code forces the disabling of the context menu.

Comment: sorry the url is not public, but you say that that may be the code disables the context menu, but I see the context menu, what i cant see is the options open in new tab and open in new window
thanks

Comment: can you post a bigger snippet of code that shows the real, full generated source? if you don't want to post publicly... you can post to a dropbox account or similar.